# Form is not processed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm writing my store in Django.

When it comes to filling out the order form, even if it is empty, the page about `successful payment` is still displayed.

Water code:

views.py

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    items = CartItem.objects.all()
    total_price = sum([item.product.price * item.quantity for item in items])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShippingAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new Order instance and associate with the user
            order = Order.objects.create(customer=request.user)

            # Associate each cart item with the order
            for item in items:
                item.order = order
                item.save()

            # Clear the cart
            items.delete()

            # Redirect to the success page
            return redirect('success')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Form has errors. Please correct them.')
    else:
        form = ShippingAddressForm()

    return render(request, 'checkout.html', {'items': items, 'total_price': total_price, 'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ShippingAddress


class ShippingAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingAddress
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'zip_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

checkout.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% if messages %}
    <div class="alert-container">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="py-5 text-center">
      <h2>Checkout form</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
          <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
          <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
        </h4>
        <ul class="list-group mb-3">
        {% for item in items %}
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
            <div>
              <h6 class="my-0">{{ item.product.name }}</h6>
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted">${{ item.product.price }}</span>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Total (USD)</span>
            <strong>${{ total_price }}</strong>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="post" action="{% url 'checkout' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="{{ form.full_name.id_for_label }}">{{ form.full_name.label }}</label>
              {{ form.full_name }}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Valid first name is required.
              </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">{{ form.address.label }}</label>
                {{ form.address }}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid last name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">{{ form.country.label }}</label>
            {{ form.country }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">{{ form.city.label }}</label>
                {{ form.city }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">{{ form.zip_code.label }}</label>
                {{ form.zip_code }}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Continue" required>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This problem appeared after I started getting items not through CartItem.objects.all(), but through CartItem.objects.all().

items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: Please attach the relivent code only this seems too much to read.

Comment: I changed the code in the question leaving only everything related to the form.

Comment: You question seems confusing. I don't understand what is the problem and where it is.

Comment: In general, I have a form (checkout.html), which appears after the cart, and the problem is that the same if you do not fill out the form, in any case the page of successful payment is displayed and the goods with the cart are deleted, that is working as it should work with a filled form

Comment: From where are you getting "page of successful payment" ? It is stored in messages object of django ?

Comment: No, it's a separate view

`@login_required
def order_success(request):
    return render(request, 'order_success.html')`

Comment: show code for `order_success` too

Comment: I already fixed it, the problem was that the models had blank=True. Thanks for your time.